# game center score submission problem

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator, cocos2d-iphone

i have integrate game center in my game ...and its working well but i have i new problem now :P
only one score is submit of user .. after that no score submit even its greater then posted score or less...
any idea what i have to exactly doo...
Regards
Haseeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use this to submit score......after being sure that the game center is available...

```
NSAutoreleasePool   *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:gameCenterCategory] autorelease];

    int64_t score1 =socre;
    scoreReporter.value = score1;
    [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) { 
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Submit failed");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Score Submited");
        }
    }];

    [pool release];
```

Comment: ..
i was selected worng option to show score in game center setting .. i was selected to show lowest score first .. now i have change dat option now its working well.. tahnx to u man... 
can u help out me in that question ...


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803522/iphone-how-do-display-leaderboard-screen-in-my-own-game-developed-in-cocos2d